# Python script works for one user, but not another on same machine

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-7

Another team created python scripts within our organization for my team to run. Up until two weeks ago, we all ran them without any problems. Then one day, some users have been unable to run them successfully on the same machine.

All users are admins with LUA disabled. All users should have the same permissions.

The complicating factor here is the team created a "framework" which generates code from a combination of the framework, and an excel file for the tests being run. This prevents me from stepping through the code and finding where it's specifically failing. Beyond that, the same exact script runs on the same machine when another user trying to run it.

Specifically, in the script, it appears that when the affected users are running the script, IEDriverserver doesn't appear to open. No errors are given.

Is there any environmental variables that could be specific to users that would cause this? Even a direction to look would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does it always fail in the same part of the Python code?  Does opening the Excel file have anything to do with it, perhaps?  I mean, if someone has the Excel file open on a network drive, and someone else is trying to write to the file, i'm pretty sure this will trigger an error, unless the Excel file is 'shared'.  Just a couple thoughts.

Comment: That’s a good thought. Unfortunately this isn’t the case here. The script makes a copy of the excel file, then opens the copy. The file does actually open. It’s when it goes to open an IE instance that it fails.

Comment: Well, IE and Excel are notoriously unstable together, especially if something gets mangled in the Cache.  Can you clear the Cache on the machine where the code fails and try it again?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In this case it didn't work, unfortunately. I know it's a unique situation, but what's going on is we open a python file which in turn opens an excel file. In the excel file is code for python to run. It takes this code, runs it, then python writes to the file whether it passed or failed. In the end we have an excel file with the steps of what was supposed to happen, and whether it passed or failed. One of the steps is to open IE. It works for one user account but not another on the same machine. I realize there's not much to work with. I wish they had a debugger for this.

Comment: I'm more-less looking for where something in the registry or other area would affect something like this... I mean, all else being equal, there has to be a difference between when one user logs in and another. These machines are in a corporate environment, and sometimes changes are pushed, and there's no real way to see what was changed. We just came in one day and some users could no longer successfully run these tests. I guess it could be group policy changes, registry changes, something was installed to certain profiles but not others... the list goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue today. I happen to solve it by unset PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH. Not sure if this helps.